# Java generic "capture#n-of" compile error

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have the following definition:

```
public interface MessageResponseHandler<T extends MessageBody> {
    public void responsed(Message<T> msg);
}

public class DeviceClientHelper {
    public MessageResponseHandler<? extends MessageBody> messageHandler;

    setHandler(MessageResponseHandler<? extends MessageBody> h){
        this.messageHandler = h;
    }

    public someMethod(Object message){
        Message<? extends MessageBody> msg = (Message<? extends MessageBody>) message;
        if (this.messageHandler != null) {
            this.messageHandler.responsed(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out why in the someMethod() method, the invocation of

```
this.messageHandler.responsed(msg);
```

would give me a wired compiler error in eclipse. something like:

```
the method responsed(Message<capture#3-of ? extends MessageBody>) in
the type MessageResponseHandler<capture#3-of ? extends MessageBody> is
not applicable for the arguments (Message<capture#4-of ? extends
MessageBody>)
```

what is the "catpure" means in the error message anyway?

Comment: This is [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at its finest.

Comment: well, i kinda of know why now. given MessageResponseHandler<? extends MessageBody> messageHandler, it has to be a certain type of MessageBody, but not the general. But how can i get around this? the type will be different every time.

Comment: @Finbarr this has nothing to do with erasure. The types are just unsound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're saying `DeviceClientHelper` has a `messageHandler` for some subclass of `MessageBody`.  And `someMethod` has a message also for some subclass of `MessageBody`.  However, there's nothing requiring them to be the *same* subclass of `MessageBody`, so the call to `responsed` is not valid.

To make them use the same subclass, make the `DeviceClientHelper` generic on a specific subclass of `MessageBody` like so:

```
interface MessageResponseHandler<T extends MessageBody> {
    public void responsed(Message<T> msg);
}

public class DeviceClientHelper<T extends MessageBody> {
    public MessageResponseHandler<T> messageHandler;

    void setHandler(MessageResponseHandler<T> h){
        this.messageHandler = h;
    }

    public void someMethod(Object message){
        Message<T> msg = (Message<T>) message;
        if (this.messageHandler != null) {
            this.messageHandler.responsed(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

However, your `MessageResponseHandler` interface probably doesn't need to care about the `MessageBody` class.  This depends on how it's actually used, but something like this might work better:

```
interface MessageResponseHandler {
    public void responsed(Message<? extends MessageBody> msg);
}
```

And then you can remove the generic type from the `messageHandler` field and keep the original `someMethod` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pitfall when using generics; despite your messageHandler and msg objects looking to be the same, they really aren't (or rather, they do not necessarily have to be). Consider this:

```
class M1 extends MessageBody { ... }
class M2 extends MessageBody { ... }

MessageHandler<? extends MessageBody> handler = new MessageHandler<M1>();
/* So far so good */
Message<? extends MessageBody> message = new M2();
/* Still OK */
handler.responded(message);
/* Huh... you don't want to allow this, right? */
```

If your handler is only able to handle one **specific** kind of messages, then your DeviceClientHelper should only receive this **specific** kind of messages too, right? How about something like this?

```
public class DeviceClientHelper<T extends MessageBody> {
    public MessageResponseHandler<T> messageHandler;

    setHandler(MessageResponseHandler<T> h){
        this.messageHandler = h;
    }

    public someMethod(Object message){
        Message<T> msg = (Message<T>) message;
        if (this.messageHandler != null) {
            this.messageHandler.responsed(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

(this will most probably produce a warning about unchecked cast)

Or better yet:

```
public class DeviceClientHelper<T extends MessageBody> {
    public MessageResponseHandler<T> messageHandler;

    setHandler(MessageResponseHandler<T> h){
        this.messageHandler = h;
    }

    public someMethod(T message){
        if (this.messageHandler != null) {
            this.messageHandler.responsed(message);
        }
    }
}
```

If your DeviceClientHelper is supposed to contain handlers handling different types of messages (for example, it initially contains a handler for M1, but then you assign a handler for M2), and still you want it to be validated by generics, I am afraid you are out of luck; this would require the generics to be checked at **runtime** instead of **compile time**, and Java does not support it due to generics' type erasure.

Comment: You lost me there. Are you assuming SomeHandler extends MessageBody? Woudln't that fail already in the handler assignment?

Comment: No, why should it? The assignment specifies that the handler for ANY type extending MessageBody can be assigned. Handler<M1> satisfies this - M1 is a type extending MessageBody. So, M1 fulfills the "? extends MessageBody" condition for the handler variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `wildcard (?)` behavior in generics. Long story short, a variable/parameter  typed with a wildcard cannot be assigned-to.

In your code, the call `this.messageHandler.responsed(msg)` tries to pass `msg` into a parameter whose type is `? extends MessageBody`.  It doesn't matter that the actual parameter that you're pssing is also wildcard-typed: as long as the actual parameter is wildcard-typed you cannot pass values to it.